# Android : Ask permission for bluetooth

Tags: android, permissions

I want to know how can I ask permission from the user to change the state of the bluetooth? I don't need for wifi because it's not mandatory.

I search the basic window where the user check the Yes or No buttons for allow app to modify the state of app.

Comment: Checkout [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: I've see that.. but how I can show the window ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will generate a popup which requests the user for permission to turn on Bluetooth. "300" is the discoverable duration to enable discovering option.

```
Intent discoverableIntent = new
Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
startActivity(discoverableIntent);
```

Follow this [Bluetooth Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) for more on Bluetooth activity.